# X11 forwarding with PuTTY/Xming with local port forwarding

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, putty, xorg

I'm currently using PuTTY to perform local port forwarding on a Windows 10 machine to connect to a remote machine using Remote Desktop Connection (connect to localhost:3390). I would like to perform X11 forwarding and use Xming to connect instead.

I've enabled X11 forwarding in PuTTY, and I've also installed Xming. I've configured Xlaunch to start PuTTY, and tried to connect to localhost:3390, but it seems that Xlaunch doesn't let me enter the port number. Nothing happens after I click on "Finish" either. I've looked at the other X11 forwarding/PuTTY guides here and elsewhere but none mention local port forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I did not realize that I am able to run X programs directly from the SSH shell I have, and it would pup up a new X window on my Windows machine.